# When should Notifications in the NSUserNotificationCenter be removed?

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

I wanted to ask about the best programming practices for using removeAllDeliveredNotifications() in the NSUserNotificationCenter. I couldn't find in any of the documentation if the NSUserNotificationCenter automatically removes delivered notifications after a certain period of time, or if the developer is responsible for removing the notifications. If the developer is responsible, when would be the optimal time or what would be the optimal place to remove the notifications, and should all delivered notifications be removed at once, or is there a recommended amount of time after which a delivered notification should be removed?

Comment: There aren't any, its whatever makes most sense for your app from the perspective of the user. As to when or if they should be removed, that is a matter of opinion and whats good for one app may not be for another.

Comment: That makes sense. I get it. If you want to add this as an answer I'll go ahead and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Truth Potatoe in the comments above (I will accept his answer if he posts it as an answer), "There aren't any, its whatever makes most sense for your app from the perspective of the user. As to when or if they should be removed, that is a matter of opinion and whats good for one app may not be for another."